# Не запускается в консли (Программа Python)

Tags: python

Я запускаю программу в консоли, ничего не выдаёт. Возможного из-за того что я на Линуксе. КОД ПИТОН!! Ну или это циклы так влияют??

```py
    while True:
        if Lan == "" or Lan == " ":
            LAN = input("Choose Your Language: En, Ru")

            if LAN == "En":
                file = open("System/Info/Language.txt", "w")
                file.write(LAN)
                file.close()
                break

            elif LAN == "Ru":
                file = open("System/Info/Language.txt", "w")
                file.write(LAN)
                file.close()
                break

        elif Lan == "Ru":

                    # Разделение!
                    listL = ["Погода", "Калькулятор"]     
                    while True:
                        Prog = input("\nЧто Будем Делать?: ")

                        if Prog not in listL:
                            print("Вы Не Правильно Ввели Действие, Повторите.")
                            continue
                        # Если Пользователь Выбрал Погоду!
                        elif Prog.lower().startswith("погода"):
                            Place = input("Введите город: ")
                            Q = len(Place)
                            W = Q - 1
                            config_dict = get_default_config()
                            config_dict["language"] = "ru"
                            owm = OWM('КЛЮЧ', config_dict)
                            mgr = owm.weather_manager()
                            observation = mgr.weather_at_place(Place)
                            w = observation.weather
                            print("Сейчас в " + Place.replace(Place, Place[:W] + "е") + str(w))

                        # Если Пользователь Выбрал Калькулятор!
                        elif Prog.lower().startswith("калькулятор"):
                            a = input("\nЧто будем делать? (+, -, *, /, **) : ")
                            b = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
                            c = float(input("Введите второе число: "))

                            if a == "+":
                                d = b + c
                                print("{} + {} = {}".format(b, c, d))
                            elif a == "-":
                                e = b - c
                                print("{} - {} = {}".format(b, c, e))
                            elif a == "*":
                                g = b * c
                                print("{} * {} = {}".format(b, c, g))
                            elif a == "/":
                                if c:
                                    p = b / c
                                    print("{} / {} = {}".format(b, c, p))
                                else:
                                    print("На Ноль Делить Нельзя")
                            elif a == "**":
                                if c:
                                    f = b ** c
                                    print("{} ** {} = {}".format(b, c, f))
                                else:
                                    print("Степень Выщитывается Без Нуля)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли оно ничего не выдаёт в консоли, ну да ладно.

Подход 1:

1. Пишем в консоли
   python3 script_name.py

Подход 2:
Всё делаем в директории со скриптом

1. пишем в консоли 'which python3'
   копируем то, что появилось
2. открываем скрипт и дописываем в самом верху
   #!/path/to/interpreter
3. в консоли пишем
   chmod +x script_name.py
4. в консоли пишем
   ./script_name.py

Правда, как я вижу, там куча лишних отступов, которые тоже было бы не лишним удалить.